# Which sentence is better to understand?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

1.Recall what the speaker just said in your head, especially the intonation, instead of orally
repeating right away.

2.In your head, recall what the speaker just said, especially the intonation, instead of orally
repeating right away.

3.Instead of orally repeating right away, recall what the speaker just said in your head,
especially the intonation.

Or what other ways to rewrite the sentence to make it more understandable?

Comment: Requests for proofreading or "please improve this" are off topic here.  If you have a question about a specific aspect of phrasing or grammar or usage, we can answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like (3) the most. It says don't do X, do Y, specifically Y'. Very direct commands, in the right order. (2) is far too disjointed and you have to guess which clauses connect where. (1) is better than (2), but you still have to know that the "instead" clause connects back to the "recall" clause and has nothing to do with the "especially" clause.

An improved (1) might use parentheses for the "especially" instead of commas, in which case I'm indifferent between that and (3). Or, you could just move the recommendation to focus on intonation into the next sentence.